# Django AJAX call/url from template after dropdown change

Tags: python, ajax, django

How do I properly have django tell me the url to send it to, so I can avoid hardcoding it, and how do I do it in JS, once it's been served (can I get the url with everything but the `recipe_pk` and then concat it in JS later?)

## url/router

```
url(r'^recipe/AJAX/(?P<recipe_pk>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?', views.newRecipeAJAX, name='newRecipeAJAX'),
```

## in the template

```
{% block script_inline %}
  $(function(){
    $('#form-dropdown').change(function () {
      var recipe_pk = $(this).val();
      {# This one doesn't know the recipe_pk yet, so it throws a NoReverseMatch error #}
      request_url = {% url 'recipes:newRecipeAJAX' recipe_pk=recipe_pk %};
      {# This one will too, since it doesn't have the argument #}
      request_url = {% url 'recipes:newRecipeAJAX' %};
      {# Tried to get a valid link, then JS remove it and add the correct pk, but it throws a JS console error of 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags'#}
      request_url = "'' + {% url 'recipes:newRecipeAJAX' recipe_pk=1 %} + "'";
      alert(requst_url)
      // AJAX Land
    });
  });
{% endblock script_inline %}
```

## view

```
def newRecipeAJAX(request, recipe_pk):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
  # GET
  else:
    recipe_requested = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=recipe_pk)
    related_recipes = Recipe.related_recipes.all()      
    return {
      'recipe_requested': recipe_requested,
      'related_recipes': related_recipes,
    }
```

Comment: your url is ending with `?`. Did you check this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines of your template where the url is formatted, as follows:

```
var recipe_pk = $(this).val();
request_url = "{% url 'recipes:newRecipeAJAX' '999' %}".replace('999', recipe_pk);
```

Explanation:  When django generates the HTML, the url tag will be interpreted on the server side, forming the following javascript:

```
request_url = "/path/to/recipe/AJAX/999/".replace('999', recipe_pk);
```

If you view source in your browser, you will see this.

Then, on the client side, when your javascript is executed, it will replace the `999` with the value of `recipe_pk`.

Use whatever placeholder you like instead of 999.. if instead you needed to replace a parameter that takes a string argument you could use something more traditional such as `__ARG__`.  Since your url regex expects an integer in this case, your placeholder must be an integer.

This is the best way I've worked out to do it.. requiring only a minor amount of extra code in the template, and none in the python.  Unfortunately Django was not originally designed with AJAX in mind...  It would be nice if there was a special reverse function which returned the URL containing the parameter names as placeholders in place of the parameter values, but so far as I know, there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a template string to the context, then use that to replace the url.

i.e. in my view

```
from django.urls import reverse

def view_that_renders_javascript(request):
    reversed_path = reverse('recipes:newRecipeAJAX', kwargs={'recipe_pk':1})
    ajax_path = '/'.join(reversed_path.split('/')[:-2]) + '/'  # '/recipe/AJAX/`
    context = {
        'ajax_path': ajax_path
    }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Then inside the template

```
{% block script_inline %}
  $(function(){
    var ajaxPath = '{{ajax_path}}';
    $('#form-dropdown').change(function () {
      var recipe_pk = $(this).val();
      request_url = ajaxPath + recipe_pk + '/';
      alert(request_url);
      // AJAX Land
    });
  });
{% endblock script_inline %}
```

In general I feel that this is an anti-pattern django encourages: Injecting runtime Javascript information through templating. Personally I would have the client load runtime config via an API endpoint, so that the server is responsible for serving information and the client is responsible for runtime state - but that's made more troublesome when you're performing a page load after every action as standard Django encourages (i.e. Django forms and such). This mixing of responsibilities can be a big source of bugs.

With that caveat out of the way, this should work with what you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should fix your problem

```
$(function(){
    $('#form-dropdown').change(function () {
    var recipe_pk = $(this).val();
    request_url = "recipe/AJAX"+recipe_pk
    alert(requst_url);
    // AJAX Land
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $('#form-dropdown').change(function () {
    var recipe_pk = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "recipe/AJAX"+recipe_pk,
        success: function(data){

        },/*./success*/
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {

        }/*  end of error */
    });
});
```